# How can I authenticate and retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault using Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-keyvault

How can I authenticate and retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault using Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets libraries? I am trying to fetch some secrets from my Azure Key Vault. To achieve this, I am utilizing the Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets and Azure.Identity libraries. Given my limited experience, my approach involves using the credentials: appId, appkey, and tenantId for authentication and then retrieving 4 secrets stored in Azure Key Vault. However, upon executing the lines like await GetSecretValueAsync(client, "secret_name"), my application seems to hang indefinitely without throwing an exception. The output simply states: "The program '[4212] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)." Am I making any mistakes? What additional steps are necessary to successfully authenticate using these credentials and retrieve the secrets?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class KeyVaultHelper
    {
        public static async Task<EntitySettings> GetCurrencyAllianceKeyVaultValue()
        {
            try
            {
                string keyVaultUrl = "my_url";

                var appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_ID"];
                var appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_KEY"];
                var tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TENANT_ID"];

                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, appId, appKey);

                var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);

                var secret1 = await GetSecretValueAsync(client, "secret_name");
                var secretKey = await GetSecretValueAsync(client, "secret_name");
                var clientId = await GetSecretValueAsync(client, "secret_name");
                var clientSecret = await GetSecretValueAsync(client, "secret_name");

                return new EntitySettings
                {
                    secret1 = publicKey,
                    secret2 = secretKey,
                    secret3 = clientId,
                    secret4 = clientSecret
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetSecretValueAsync(SecretClient client, string secretName)
        {
            KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
            return secret.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it being called from ASP.NET? If yes, then you might be seeing HttpClient Hang. Can you try :  KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName).ConfigureAwait(false);
The code you have shared mostly seemed ok. Although I will advise using managed identity to securely access your secrets.

Comment: Thanks @Daredevil with this I'm able to see the response off GetSecretAsync.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daredevil noted, calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` is generally recommended for most libraries and many apps, including web apps.

I did want to point out some of our [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration) for using the Key Vault SDKs more effectively in ASP.NET using the configuration provider.

We also recommend that you use [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential) which can use environment variables you could set for local development, but is optimized for hosting in Azure to use [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity), which is much more secure.

Because you're using configuration variables locally, you could, for example, use:

```cs
TokenCredential credential = null;
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  credential = new ClientSecretCredential(/*like you configured above*/);
}
else
{
  credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
}
```

Typically, `DefaultAzureCredential` is all you need if you use environment variables in development or in production, though Managed Identity in production is still recommended.